# How can I merge two field arrays in many documents into a single set?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have MongoDB collection data that looks like this:

```js
{ "_id" : "1", "array1" : [ "1", "2" ] },
{ "_id" : "2", "array2" : [ "1", "3" ] },
{ "_id" : "3", "array1" : [ ] },
{ "_id" : "4", "array2" : [ ] },
{ "_id" : "5" },
{ "_id" : "6", "array1" : [ "3", "4" ], "array2" : [ "5" ] }
```

I would like to find a query that simply returns the unique array values in a single array like so:

```js
{"_id":"theID", "result":["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]}
```

The id isn't important. Note that either `array1`, `array2`, both or neither can be present in a document and that they can even be empty. I have tried many aggregations and cascading query commands and just can't come up with desired response.

Comment: This is not as easy as I thought it would be. My idea was to first squash both arrays into one using `$setUnion`, then `$unwind` the resulting array and then `$group` them with `$addToSet`, but unfortunately `$setUnion` doesn't work unless both fields are present in the document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you will need to use the `.aggregate()` method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline.

The first stage in the pipeline uses the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator to filter out those documents where both `array1` and `array2` are not presents using the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator and the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). This operator reduce the number of documents to be processed in the down in the pipeline.

The next stage is the [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) where you basically use the [`$setUnion`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/)  to return an array containing the elements that appear in any of your array; it also filters out duplicates elements in its result. Also not the use of the [`$ifNull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator which returns the value of the first expression or empty array depending on whether the first expression evaluates to null (here expression are "array1" and "array2"). 
From there, you need to de-normalize the "arrays" field using the [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator.

In the last stage of the pipeline you [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) accumulator operator which returns an array of unique value.

```js
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "$or": [ 
            { "array1.0": { "$exists": true } }, 
            { "array2.0": { "$exists": true } }
        ]
    }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "arrays": { 
            "$setUnion": [ 
                { "$ifNull": [ "$array1", [] ] },
                { "$ifNull": [ "$array2", [] ] } 
            ] 
        }
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$arrays" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "arrays": { "$addToSet": "$arrays" } 
    }} 
] )
```

Which yields:

```js
{ "_id" : null, "arrays" : [ "5", "3", "1", "4", "2" ] }
```

Comment: using `$ifNull` is important with `$setUnion` otherwise you get NULL if one array is empty